# Running percentage calculation in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, percentage, cumulative-sum

I have calculated running total as below, when I am trying to calculate running %, it gives wrong values

```
Quarter Status          
Closed  Closed %    Open    Open%   Total   Total %
Q1  16  21.62        58     78.38   74     100
Q2  29  17.57        119    82.34   148    100
Q3  29               191    100     220    100
```

% values displayed are actual percentage values of the cell count and not the ones calculated on the running total count

How do I fix this

Expected output:

```
Quarter Status          
Closed  Closed %    Open    Open%   Total   Total %
Q1  16  21.62162    58  78.37838    74  100
Q2  29  19.59459    119 80.40541    148 100
Q3  29  13.18182    191 86.81818    220 100
```

I have tried % total all options

Comment: Read about Table calcs, partitioning and addressing in the online help. Try some of the Hands on Training exercises from previous Tableau conferences, such as http://tc19.tableau.com - go watch the sessions and search for Hands on Training sessions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Edit Table Calculation and setting the calculation to restart every [Quarter]? Right click on the table calculation in the view to set different "Compute Using" fields.